# No audio sound in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running on Windows 7 64 bit.

```
Android 2.3.3
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

I delete the emulator and make a new one without snapshot enabled and i have been doing this in order for the audio to work but there should be a way to fix it.. and my computer audio is working without any issue.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google API 2.1 Updated. Make sure that you are not using snapshot. Try without snapshot. 
I am using Google API 2.1 updated and sound is coming without any issue. But i tried to use snap shot of it and sound was not coming even though audio was playing.

Answer (score 0):

try to press CTRL + F5
refer to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html